# ArrayPHP Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm testing this code because I want to get the value of &posted_data['sample'] from two different variables **($total and $currentcy)**. Can anyone give me a clue of how to do that? I've been reading about it and testing some codes, but nothing! According to this code, the output shuld be **1000€**

This is my code:

```
$currency = '€';
$wedding_budget = '2000,00';

if(trim(strlen($wedding_budget)) >= '6') {

    $wedding_budget =  preg_replace('/[\.,]/', '', $wedding_budget );

} else {

    $wedding_budget = preg_replace('/\.[0-9]{1,2}$/', '', $wedding_budget);

}

$total = $wedding_budget / 2;
$posted_data['sample'] = compact('total', 'currency');
echo $posted_data['sample'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will achieve what you want in an easier way

```
$currency = '€';
$wedding_budget = '2000,00';

$wedding_budget = str_replace(',', '.', $wedding_budget);

$total = $wedding_budget / 2;
$posted_data['sample'] = $total . $currency;
echo $posted_data['sample'];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$posted_data['sample']; is an array. You can print by:

```
echo $posted_data['sample']['total'];
echo $posted_data['sample']['currency'];
```

Regards